# Sign distribution certificate for client

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

We're developing an app for a client and it's now time to start testing externally. 
Obviously we don't want to give the source code to client for signing and uploading the app. 
Client has already added us as admin to their account but we cannot create any certificates.
Has anyone any tips on how to do this?
Many thanks

Comment: do you created development and distribution cert so far?

Comment: No. Obviously we got our own but the client did not. Nor we can create them for him

Comment: okay let me list down steps for you to create Adhoc profile.

Comment: how adHoc profile will help me with this? I need to be able to test flight through the client's account

Answer (score 0):

1) Open developer.apple.com

2) Create Ad Hoc provisioning profile.
[image]

3) Select App Id
[image]

4) Select Distribution Certificate
[image]

5) Select devices to allow installation.
[image]

6) Create and download newly installed AdHoc provisioning profile.

7) Create xarchive of project and sign it with AdHoc profile.

8) Upload generated ipa file at
https://www.diawi.com

It generates link, open this link in safari of iPhone, then app will be installed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But how is my client going to upload this bundle for TestFlight through his account?

Comment: Thanks again. Not what I'm looking for. I want the client to upload app to his account and test it through TestFlight to devices that I don't know or have access to. At the moment we are testing app through our account using TestFlight to a list of beta testers. BUT now he wants to have the app tested via his account!

Comment: @GeorgeAsda if you need Testflight, you need to submit ipa on App Store, then follow instructions on link https://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial to enable users for TestFlight

Comment: @GeorgeAsda you need to upload application to test flight using your client certificate and Provision profile